New to using SAS arrays and can't get array elements to populate with values based on IF-THEN-ELSE statement
Admittedly, I've never written an array, so I'm sure this is an easy solution for most users.  I've got a dataset with two columns:
START_BLOCK (possible integer values 0-47)
END_BLOCK (possible integer values 0-47)
I'm trying to create an array that adds fields TIME_BLOCK_0 through TIME_BLOCK_47 and inserts a 1 or 0 based on whether that time block [i] falls between (inclusive) START_BLOCK and END_BLOCK
For example, a record with START_BLOCK = 29 and END_BLOCK = 31 would have a value of 0 in every column except columns TIME_BLOCK_29, TIME_BLOCK_30, and TIME_BLOCK_31 which would be populated with a 1.
This is my first time asking for help on here so I apologize if my question isn't clear.
The code I tried (that did create the TIME_BLOCK_[i] fields but did not populate them) was:
data WANT (drop = i);
set HAVE;
array time_blocks[48] time_block_0 - time_block_47;
do i = 0 to 47;

* midnight = time block 0;

* First, account for cases that end on a different day than they start (where the end_block is < the start_block)- not common;
if end_block < start_block then do;
    if end_block >= i or start_block <= i then time_block_i = 1; else time_block_i = 0;
    end;
* then, for cases where start_block < end_block (most cases that start and end on the same day) - most common;
else if start_block <= [i] and end_block >= [i] then time_block_i = 1; else time_block_i = 0;

end;

run;



Show the values of START_BLOCK and END_BLOCK you used.

It will be less confusing if you tell SAS to use indexes of 0 to 47 instead of the normal 1 to 48.
Let's first make some example data so we have something to test with.
data have;
  input start_block end_block;
cards;
0 47
2 4
-1 56
56 -1
;

Since SAS evaluates boolean expressions as either 0 (FALSE) or 1 (TRUE) you can skip the IF/THEN logic and just use an assignment statement.  (Also don't bother using dataset options to DROP a variable. A simple DROP statement is all you need. Save the complication of dataset options for when you have to use them.)
data WANT ;
  set HAVE;
  array time_blocks[0:47] time_block_0 - time_block_47;
  do index = 0 to 47;
    time_blocks[index] = start_block <= index <= end_block;
  end;
  drop index;
run;


In comments you seem to say the actual data is time of day values for surgeries.  In that case use the actual datetime values and loop between them.
Initialize the array to zeros, then loop between the start and end by half-hour increments and then increment the appropriate variable.
data have;
  input start :datetime. end :datetime.;
  format start end datetime19.;
cards;
01JAN2024:00:15 01JAN2024:04:35 
01JAN2024:22:15 02JAN2024:03:00 
;

data WANT ;
  set HAVE;
  array time_blocks[0:47] time_block_0 - time_block_47;
  do index = 0 to 47; time_blocks[index] = 0; end;
  do datetime=start to end by '00:30:00't ;
    time_blocks[int(timepart(datetime)/'00:30:00't)]+1;
  end;
  drop index datetime;
run;

If you only have time of day but not actual datetime values then just convert them.  So use DAY=0 when converting START_TIME to a datetime value and when END_TIME is less than START_TIME then use DAY=1 when converting it to a datetime value.  Example:
start = dhms(0,0,0,start_time);
end = dhms(end_time<start_time,0,0,end_time);
format start_time end_time tod5. start end datetime19.;


Thanks Tom, that's close to what I need!  The only thing it doesn't account for is a case where START_BLOCK < END_BLOCK.  For example, if I have a record with START_BLOCK = 47 and END_BLOCK = 4, then I want the following fields populated with a value of 1:
TIME_BLOCK_1 - TIME_BLOCK_4 and TIME_BLOCK_47
For context, these start and end blocks are surgical case times by half hour increments of time during a 24 hour period, where TIME_BLOCK_0 = midnight and TIME_BLOCK_47 = 11:30pm.  So a record where START_BLOCK < END_BLOCK means the surgery started one day and ended the next day.

First you need to convert your TIME values into DATETIME values. Then START will be less than END since it will be on a different day.  What is it that you want to DO when the surgery started on a different day?  What units do the 0 to 47 represent?  Half hour intervals in a day?  Are you trying to detect what time blocks are most frequently used?  I would set the whole array to zeros and then loop from start datetime to end datetime by half hours and just update the appropriate variable. If the surgery was over 24 hours long then some of the block values will be larger than 1.

Yes, each of them represents a half hour interval during the day.  0 = 12:00am-12:29am, 1 = 12:30am-12:59am, ...  47 = 11:30pm-11:59pm.
For each record (representing a surgery) I just need to flag what time blocks that case took place.  The start_block (0-47) represents what time_block (0-47) the case started, and the end_block (0-47) represents what time_block (0-47) the case ended.  It's these overnight cases that start later at night (e.g. time_block_47) and end early the next day (e.g. time_block_4) that don't work with your original solution (which is otherwise great!)

I got it to work!  Your suggestions were tremendously helpful, I just had to make one minor tweak to round the start and end times down to the nearest half hour (I was occasionally missing the 1 in the last column otherwise):
data WANT;
set HAVE;
array time_blocks[0:47] time_block_0 - time_block_47;
do index = 0 to 47; time_blocks[index] = 0; end;
do datetime=intnx('minute30',start,0,'b') to intnx('minute30',end,0,'b') by '00:30:00't ;
time_blocks[int(timepart(datetime)/'00:30:00't)]+1;
end;
drop index datetime;
run;
Thank you so much for your help on this!

A SAS Variable based array allows you to specify which variables are to be addressable via array syntax.  Specifying variable names after the array name will create new variables if they don't already exist.
Don't forget that variables are reset to missing at the top of the implicit DATA Step loop.  If you are trying to 'fill-in' array elements over a by group then the arrayed variables will also need to be retained and reset at the start of the by-group.  If the array variables are part of the data set be read by SET you might needed an 'adjacent' array that will not have certain elements getting a value overwritten.
Example:
Because you want 0/1 in each slot, you will want to loop over the entire array and set the element to the result of a logical evaluation (which is 0-false, 1-true)
The logic expression shown here a <= b <= c is specific to SAS and means a <= b and b <= c
data want ;
  set have ;
  array slot time_block_0-time_block_47 ;  * 48 variables ;
  do index = 1 to dim(slot) ;
    slot[index] = start_block <= index <= end_block ;
  end ;
run ;

